# Multiple OfType Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query that selects all textboxes in a placeholder and adds them to a list using a struct. I need to expand this functionality to also take the selectedvalue of a DropDownList I am pretty sure I am doing this wrong, because when I debug the method the lists count is 0.

My own guess is that declaring 2 `OfType<>()` is wrong, but I am pretty new to linq and I have no idea of how else to do it.

Any help would be awesome! Thanks in advance.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public struct content
{
    public string name;
    public string memberNo;
    public int points;
    public string carclass;
}

List<content> rows = new List<content>();

protected void LinkButton_Submit_Attendees_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
List<content> rows = PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().OfType<DropDownList>()
        .Select(txt => new
        {
            Txt = txt,
            Number = new String(txt.ID.SkipWhile(c => !Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray())
        })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Number)
        .Select(g => new content
        {
            carclass = g.First(x => x.Txt.ID.StartsWith("DropDownlist_CarClass")).Txt.SelectedValue,
            name = g.First(x => x.Txt.ID.StartsWith("TextBox_Name")).Txt.Text,
            memberNo = g.First(x => x.Txt.ID.StartsWith("TextBox_MemberNo")).Txt.Text,
            points = int.Parse(g.First(x => x.Txt.ID.StartsWith("TextBox_Points")).Txt.Text)
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

Here's the method that creates the controls.

```
protected void createcontrols()
{
    int count = 0;
    if (ViewState["count"] != null)
    {
        count = (int)ViewState["count"];
    }
    while (PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.Count < count)
    {
        TextBox TextBox_Name = new TextBox();
        TextBox TextBox_MemberNo = new TextBox();
        TextBox TextBox_Points = new TextBox();
        DropDownList DropDownList_CarClass = new DropDownList();
        DropDownList_CarClass.Items.Add("Car1");
        ...
        DropDownList_CarClass.Items.Add("Car2");
        TextBox_Name.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Navn");
        TextBox_Name.ID = "TextBox_Name" + PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.Count.ToString();
        TextBox_Name.CssClass = "input-small";
        TextBox_MemberNo.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Medlemsnr.");
        TextBox_MemberNo.ID = "TextBox_MemberNo" + PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.Count.ToString();
        TextBox_MemberNo.CssClass = "input-small";
        TextBox_Points.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Point");
        TextBox_Points.ID = "TextBox_Points" + PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.Count.ToString();
        TextBox_Points.CssClass = "input-small";
        PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.Add(TextBox_Name);
        PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.Add(TextBox_MemberNo);
        PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.Add(DropDownList_CarClass);
        PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.Add(TextBox_Points);
        PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can use the `Where` and check if the instance of object `is` of type!

```
List<content> rows = PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(c => c is TextBox || c is DropDownList)
        .Select(txt => new
        {
            Txt = txt,
            Number = new String(txt.ID.SkipWhile(c => !Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray())
        })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Number)
        .Select(g => new content
        {
            carclass = g.First(x => x.Txt.ID.StartsWith("DropDownlist_CarClass")).Txt.SelectedValue,
            name = g.First(x => x.Txt.ID.StartsWith("TextBox_Name")).Txt.Text,
            memberNo = g.First(x => x.Txt.ID.StartsWith("TextBox_MemberNo")).Txt.Text,
            points = int.Parse(g.First(x => x.Txt.ID.StartsWith("TextBox_Points")).Txt.Text)
        })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Just instead of `.OfType<>()`?

Comment: @KasperMackenhauerJacobsen yes!

Comment: replace `List<content> rows = PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().OfType<DropDownList>()` with `List<content> rows = PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.Where(c => c is TextBox || c is DropDownList)`

Comment: I get this error when I paste in your code:`
`Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.ControlCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.ControlCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: ControlCollection implements IEnumerable, you do have `using System.Linq` namespace ?

Comment: @AppDeveloper: The `Select` extension method is defined on the generic `IEnumerable<T>` interface (not the non-generic `IEnumerable`). For your code to work, you'd need to first call `Cast<Control>()` (or convert to a generic `IEnumerable<Control>` in some other way).

Comment: @DanTao Can you perhaps show me how I'd do that using my code? I'm not sure how to do it, would I replace OfType with Cast or?

Comment: @KasperMackenhauerJacobsen - i updated the code according to Dan's comment!

Answer (score 11):

[AppDeveloper is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15452191/105570). `OfType<T>` filters out all objects of types other than `T`; so by filtering twice, you effectively eliminate all objects in the list.

If you wanted to wrap this logic (filtering all but *two* types from a list) into something reusable, nothing's stopping you from implementing your own extension method:

```
using System.Collections;

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable OfType<T1, T2>(this IEnumerable source)
    {
        foreach (object item in source)
        {
            if (item is T1 || item is T2)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Including the above class in your project will allow you to write code like this in your application:

```
var textBoxesAndDropDowns = controls.OfType<TextBox, DropDownList>();
```

To learn more about extension methods, see [the MSDN article on the subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx).

Note that since the extension method above "lets in" two different types, the result is still a non-generic `IEnumerable` sequence. If you wanted to treat the result as a generic sequence (e.g., an `IEnumerable<Control>`), I would recommend using the `Cast<T>` extension method:

```
var filteredControls = controls.OfType<TextBox, DropDownList>().Cast<Control>();
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was what I was doing wrong :)
I'm not sure how to use your solution though, I pasted it into my class but I am not able to use it like `.OfType<>()`

Comment: @KasperMackenhauerJacobsen - you need to specify the type's before calling that function! i have added a example to Dan Tao's answer!

Comment: @AppDeveloper That's what I tried, it gives me this `error: Compiler Error Message: CS1106: Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class` It just uses the orginal `OfType` with one overload

Comment: @KasperMackenhauerJacobsen - please add an extra static class in your project `any class name` is ok. and paste the code there.

Comment: @AppDeveloper After adding a new static class this error comes up on `.Select`:

`Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @KasperMackenhauerJacobsen - please change the method signature to `public static IEnumerable<Control> OfType<T1, T2>(this IEnumerable source) where T1 : Control  T2 : Control`

Comment: @AppDeveloper [I've moved this to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26301/discussion-between-kasper-mackenhauer-jacobsen-and-appdeveloper) if that's ok, seems SO isn't fond of long comment threads

Answer (score 3):

I haven't read the question thoroughly, but from what the title implies, you can achieve the behavior with:

```
var collection = new object[] { 5, "4545",  'd', 54.5 , 576 };

var allowedTypes = new[] { typeof(string), typeof(int) }; 
var result = collection
 .Where(item => allowedTypes.Contains(item.GetType()));
```

See it in action [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C1n90o).

Answer (score 0):

Took @Shimmys answer for an extension method:

```
/// <param name="wantedTypes">--- Sample: --- new Type[] { typeof(Label), typeof(Button) }</param>
public static IEnumerable OfTypes(this IEnumerable collection, Type[] wantedTypes)
{
    if (wantedTypes == null)
        return null;
    else
        return collection.Cast<object>().Where(element => wantedTypes.Contains(element.GetType()));
}
```

Usage:

```
// List of 3 different controls
List<object> controls = new List<object>(new object[] { new Label(), new Button(), new TextBox() });

// Get all labels and buttons
var labelsAndButtons = controls.OfTypes(new Type[] { typeof(Label), typeof(Button) });
```

Answer (score -2):

Your problem is in the `OfType<>().OfType<>()` you filter twice with different types