# Unable to cast object of Type1 to type Type2?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to validate a bunch of controls within a `GroupBox` in a form based application.

I cannot seem to map the `ComboBox` to the application for it to recognize and generate the error and it only does so for the `TextBox`.

```
private void groupBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control control in groupBox1.Controls)
    {
        string controlType = control.GetType().ToString();
        var lst = new List<string>() { "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox" ,"System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox"};

        //if (controlType == "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox")
        if (lst.Contains(controlType, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)control;
            ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)control;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(combo.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(txtBox.Name + " Can not be empty");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error I am receiving:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'.

Comment: Well, a combobox *isn't* a textbox, what are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Are you relaly look for `as` which will evaluate to `null` if it cannot be cast? `TextBox txtBox = control as TextBox;` ?

Comment: Also, why not simply go for `control.Text` ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks that did the trick

Comment: You are typecasting control to both textbox and Combobox, how it is possible, if you want to check whether the control is textbox or Combobox then you can use safe typecast

Comment: Here's a clever multi-type extension  of `Enumerable.OfType`  which you can use for this task: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15452327/284240

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you just want to check the `Text` and `Name` property and because the both `TextBox` and `ComboBox` inherits from `Control` class you don't need casting here. This should works for you:

```
foreach (Control control in groupBox1.Controls)
{
    if (!lst.Contains(control.GetType().ToString(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) continue;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(control.Name + " Can not be empty");
    }
}
```

Or with Linq:

```
foreach (Control control in from Control control in groupBox1.Controls 
                                    where lst.Contains(control.GetType().ToString(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                    where string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text) 
                                    select control)
{
    MessageBox.Show(control.Name + " Can not be empty");
}
```

Comment: The problem there is that the grupbox may have other things apart from textboxs and combos that dont need to be checked

Comment: @Aimnox...And then the OP could check for that by his way like this: `if (lst.Contains(control.GetType().ToString(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`

Answer (score 3):

Let's summarize what you want to do:

1. For each control inside `groupBox1`
2. ... of type TextBox or ComboBox
3. Validate that the control is not empty, if it is, show a message box

Here's some important points:

1. Every control that inherits from `Control` has a public `Text` property, you don't really need to know if it is a textbox or a combobox for this part
2. No control is *both* a textbox and a combobox (that is, no control class inherits from both `TextBox` and `ComboBox`), so one of those casts will fail every time
3. You could use `as` instead of the hard cast, which would return `null` in the cast of a cast that cannot be done, but with point 1. above this is not necessary

So here is the rewritten code with the above knowledge:

```
private void groupBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control control in groupBox1.Controls)
    {
        if (!(control is TextBox || control is ComboBox))
            continue;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text))
            continue;
        MessageBox.Show(control.Name + " Can not be empty");
    }
}
```

Note that if you want to do other things as well, which *would* need to know if the control is a textbox or a combobox, I would instead rewrite it as follows:

```
private void groupBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control control in groupBox1.Controls)
    {
        var textbox = control as TextBox;
        if (textbox != null)
        {
            ... do your processing of textboxes here
            continue;
        }
        var combobox = control as ComboBox;
        if (combobox != null)
        {
            ... do your processing of comboboxes here
            continue;
        }
        ... do your processing of other controls here
    }
}
```

Comment: Incorrect conditional operator. Should be `||` not `or`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I get from sitting in SQL all morning :)

Answer (score 3):

In your code, it cast any textbox and any combo into a textbox AND a combo.

You need to cast it to what it is only.

```
private void groupBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control control in groupBox1.Controls)
    {
        if (control is ComboBox)
        {
            ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)control;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(combo.Text)) MessageBox.Show(combo.Name + " Can not be empty");
        }
        else if (control is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)control;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox.Text)) MessageBox.Show(txtBox.Name + " Can not be empty");
        }
    }
}
```

If the groupbox only have textbox and combobox you can also do:

```
private void groupBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (dynamic control in groupBox1.Controls)
    {               
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text)) MessageBox.Show(control.Name + " Can not be empty");              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `is` operator to check whether you have the right type:

```
if(control is TextBox)
{
  TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)control;

  // Do something with txtBox
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox.Text))
  {
      MessageBox.Show(txtBox.Name + " Can not be empty");
  }
}

if(control is ComboBox)
{
  ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)control;

  // Do something with combo
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(combo.Text))
  {
      MessageBox.Show(combo.Name + " Can not be empty");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @LasseV.Karlsen pointed out, I was taking the long route by individually adding in each control. I simply added control instead of something rather than specific controls.

Here is what my updated code looks like now:

```
foreach (Control control in groupBox1.Controls)
        {
            string controlType = control.GetType().ToString();
            var lst = new List<string>() { "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox" ,"System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox"};

            //if (controlType == "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox")
            if (lst.Contains(controlType, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
               // TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)control;
               // ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)control;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(control.Name + " Can not be empty");
                }
            }
```